# SQL Query, I need 1 line per person with lowest Id of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

```
SELECT 
    Mem.MemberID, Mem.LastName + ', ' + Mem.FirstName AS Name, 
    MD.DiagnosisID, 
    Diag.DiagnosisDescription, 
    DC.DiagnosisCategoryID, DC.CategoryDescription, DC.CategoryScore
FROM 
    Member AS Mem
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    MemberDiagnosis AS MD ON Mem.MemberID = MD.MemberID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Diagnosis AS Diag ON MD.DiagnosisID = Diag.DiagnosisID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DiagnosisCategoryMap AS Map ON Map.DiagnosisID = Diag.DiagnosisID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DiagnosisCategory AS DC ON DC.DiagnosisCategoryID = Map.DiagnosisCategoryID
ORDER BY 
    Name ASC
```

I have this query, which returns the following results:

```
ID  | Name          | D.ID | D.Desc         | C.ID | C. Desc     | C.Score
----+---------------+------+----------------+------+-------------+----------
2   | Smith, Jack   | NULL | NULL           | NULL | NULL        | NULL
1   | Smith, John   | 2    | Test Diagnosis | 2    | Category B  | 20
1   | Smith, John   | 4    | Test Diagnosis | 3    | Category C  | 30
3   | Smyth, Will   | 3    | Test Diagnosis | 3    | Category C  | 30
3   | Smyth, Will   | 4    | Test Diagnosis | 3    | Category C  | 30
```

With in that query and result set, how can I go about returning 1 line per person with;

1. The lowest Diagnosis ID and it's desc.
2. The lowest Category ID with desc and score.
3. In stead of null category, return Category ID 1 and its desc and score.

Comment: The answer varies depending on your database vendor (there's one answer for MySQL, and a different answer for just about everybody else).  What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT T1.*,Diag2.DiagnosisDescription, DC2.CategoryDescription, DC2.CategoryScore 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 

    Mem.MemberID, Mem.LastName + ', ' + Mem.FirstName AS Name, 
    MIN(MD.DiagnosisID) OVER(PARTITION BY  Mem.MemberID) AS DiagnosisID, 

    MIN(ISNULL(DC.DiagnosisCategoryID,1)) OVER(PARTITION BY  Mem.MemberID) AS DiagnosisCategoryID
FROM 
    Member AS Mem
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    MemberDiagnosis AS MD ON Mem.MemberID = MD.MemberID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Diagnosis AS Diag ON MD.DiagnosisID = Diag.DiagnosisID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DiagnosisCategoryMap AS Map ON Map.DiagnosisID = Diag.DiagnosisID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DiagnosisCategory AS DC ON ISNULL(DC.DiagnosisCategoryID,1) = ISNULL(Map.DiagnosisCategoryID,1) ) AS T1 

LEFT JOIN   Diagnosis AS Diag2 ON T1.DiagnosisID = Diag2.DiagnosisID
LEFT JOIN   DiagnosisCategory AS DC2 ON T1.DiagnosisCategoryID = DC2.DiagnosisCategoryID
ORDER BY T1.NAME
```

Comment: Almost gave me what i'm looking for. Only issue is, Jack who didn't have a diagnosis didn't show up with this query. Though it did what I needed it to do for the other two. Which, given the first left outer join it should've pulled, no?

Comment: @ShaneWorkman just replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`. i updated my answer check it out